# customizing tabbar controller with storyboard referencing

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have a tabbar application where I created a storyboard referencing to have all the modules have their own storyboard. I already fixed the issue where tabbar images or title not coming when reference was made. my issue is that I want to change tabbarcontrollers tab items images and titles using custom tabbar class, its working fine when you do it through storyboard. but I need to make some customization using custom class. can any one let me know is it possible to do it programmatically or not?

**EDIT:**
Already have subclass tabbarviewcontroller but changing of title and image in it does not changing anything on tabbar.

also please fine below images of tabbar :

[[image: first image[1]]

[image: second image]

Comment: Subclass your custom `class` and set in the `storyboard` for `tabBar`.

Comment: I already did that but it is not changing any thing

Comment: It will be better if you can share what you have tried. Meanwhile have a look at this https://github.com/kamirana4/SwiftComponents

Comment: can you please first read the issue. the issue is refactoring , if I don't do refactoring its working fine programmatically.

Comment: Share the custom tab bar subclass' code